# Return status of SleepDisabled in Applescript

Tags: applescript, sleep-wake

I'm trying to do an Applescript to enable or not SleepDisabled (using pmset) depending on the state of SleepDisabled.

Something like :

```
set SuperSleep to do shell script "return status of SleepDisabled"
if SuperSleep is equal to "0" then
do shell script "sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1" user name "Myname" password "Mypassword" with administrator privileges
else
do shell script "sudo pmset -a disablesleep 0" user name "Myname" password "Mypassword" with administrator privileges
```

I tried looking into `man psmet` or using `defaults read` but no success.

The only thing I'm thinking of is using `pmset -g` to shows up this :

```
System-wide power settings:
 SleepDisabled      0
Currently in use:
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 proximitywake        0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         2
 sleep                2 (sleep prevented by coreaudiod, coreaudiod)
 tcpkeepalive         1
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            10
```

And then look up the status of SleepDisabled on the list, but I don't know how to return the "0" or "1" of SleepDisabled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
set SuperSleep to (do shell script "pmset -g | awk '/SleepDisabled/{print $2}'")

if SuperSleep is equal to "0" then
    do shell script "pmset -a disablesleep 1" with administrator privileges
else
    do shell script "pmset -a disablesleep 0" with administrator privileges
end if
```

**NOTE:** Do not use `sudo` in a `do shell script` *command*, Just use `with administrator privileges` as it's all that's needed when you'd normally do `sudo` in **Terminal** or a `bash` *script*. Additionally I would not include the `user name "Myname"` and `password "Mypassword"` as it is not encrypted in the file. Just type it into the dialog box brought up by the `administrator privileges` *option*.

Also note that `SleepDisabled` was not present in the output of `pmset -g` when I first tried in **Terminal**, and was not present until I used the `sudp pmset -a disablesleep 0` *command* from **Terminal**. If this is the case on your system you'd need to adjust the *code* to handle that situation. You could use an [if (compound)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-127122) *control statement*.

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Comment: ''pmset -g | awk '/SleepDisabled/{print $2}' '' was acutally the command line I was looking for, thanks ! I will take a look at the statement you suggest, and use ''with administrator privileges'' for more safety ;)