# Keep MacBook on when closed without keyboard and mouse

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, power, closed-clamshell

I use my Mac a lot to show movies or play video games on a larger display without a keyboard or mouse attached.

How can I set up my Mac so that it continues to display to an external screen when closed without a keyboard or mouse attached?

Comment: There’s no easy way to avoid closed clamshell. Why not connect a mouse to get your functionality?

Comment: @bmike When going from place to place such as campus screens or a friends house, it doesn’t make sense for me to carry around an entire keyboard and mouse at all times.

Comment: You’re using the wrong tool for the job.  Since this functionality is *outside* of macOS and part of the hardware, you have two choices:  use a travel mouse as it’s small and cheap, or get a Mac mini.

Comment: @Allan There is definitely a way to do this, there always is. I understand now though that there is definitely no _native_ way to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Mac to sleep when lid closed on Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361384/prevent-mac-to-sleep-when-lid-closed-on-mojave)

Answer (score 0):

I would connect a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse if you can’t have physical cables connected.

This function is in firmware, so you’d need to engineer a solution to change Apple’s conditions for closed clamshell mode.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834

Comment: Bluetooth mouse and keyboard are still physical haha. I am open to third party software