# Why is my MacBook going to sleep when it's configured not to?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, sleep-wake

I have a MacBook Pro running High Sierra. Except when I travel, I use it in clamshell mode, with an external monitor and keyboard. It's also plugged into to a UPS.

In Energy Saver > Power Adapter, I have the following options checked:

- Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off
- Wake for WiFi network access
- Enable Power Nap while plugged into a power adapter (I just enabled this last week because I'd noticed that Time Machine was sometimes not restarting each day, but the problem I'm having predates this change).

Despite these settings, it appears that the computer is going to sleep at night. I used the Terminal command

```
pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  " -e " DarkWake "
```

and the output for today is

```
2020-11-05 03:04:35 -0500 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 3634 secs 
2020-11-05 04:05:09 -0500 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] due to RTC/Maintenance: Using AC (Charge:100%) 287 secs  
2020-11-05 04:09:56 -0500 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 4270 secs 
2020-11-05 05:21:06 -0500 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] due to RTC/Maintenance: Using AC (Charge:100%) 85 secs   
2020-11-05 05:22:31 -0500 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 4789 secs 
2020-11-05 06:42:20 -0500 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] due to ARPT/Network: Using AC (Charge:100%) 70 secs   
2020-11-05 06:43:30 -0500 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 1422 secs 
2020-11-05 07:07:12 -0500 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] due to RTC/SleepService: Using AC (Charge:100%) 69 secs   
2020-11-05 07:08:21 -0500 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Sleep Service Back to Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 3553 secs 
2020-11-05 08:07:34 -0500 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] due to RTC/Maintenance: Using AC (Charge:100%) 73 secs   
2020-11-05 08:08:47 -0500 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 2066 secs 
2020-11-05 08:43:13 -0500 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNPB] due to RTC/Maintenance: Using AC (Charge:100%) 69 secs   
2020-11-05 08:44:22 -0500 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using AC (Charge:100%) 3988 secs 
2020-11-05 09:50:50 -0500 DarkWake              DarkWake from Normal Sleep [CDNP] due to XHC1/HID Activity: Using AC (Charge:100%) 0 secs    
2020-11-05 09:50:50 -0500 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] due to HID Activity: Using AC (Charge:100%)
```

Why is it going to sleep due to clamshell sleep? Isn't that supposed to be disabled when there's an external monitor connected?

Comment: It might be worth resetting the SMC and seeing if that fixes the problem: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: @negacao I reset my SMC a couple weeks ago for a [different reason](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/424910/is-it-a-battery-problem-or-smc-problem) and it looks like it fixed the problem. Too bad that reason is also why I'm replacing this MacBook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the SMC to try to address [Is it a battery problem or SMC problem?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/424910/is-it-a-battery-problem-or-smc-problem) appears to have resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I've provided in one of my other answers, all you need is one line of code to fix this:
[Prevent Mac to sleep when lid closed on Mojave / Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361384/prevent-mac-to-sleep-when-lid-closed-on-mojave-catalina/361398#361398)