# Is it a battery problem or SMC problem?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power-management

I have a mid-2015 MacBook Pro running High Sierra. Except when I'm traveling, I always use it in clamshell mode and connected to power. I rarely put it to sleep (I have Energy Saver set to just put the display to sleep).

On July 21 I noticed that the light on the power connector had gone to amber, but Energy Saver said that the battery was fully charged. However, coconutBattery said the battery was at 95%.

Today I noticed that the lightning bolt was no longer showing on the battery status in the menu bar, and when I click on it it says "Battery is not charging". Energy Saver says that the battery is at 97%, but coconutBattery says 81%. Here's its full report:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Current Charge | 6347 mAh |
| Full Charge Capacity | 7092 mAh |
| 89.5% |  |
| Design Capacity | 8755 mAh |
| 81% |  |
| Manufacture date | 2018-03-07 |
| Cycle Count | 31 |
| MacOS battery status | Good |
| Battery temperature | 37.0°C |
| Charging with | 0 Watts |
| Power adapter | Connected |

Does this look like a problem with the battery, power adapter, or SMC?

UPDATE:

I reset the SMC, and at first it seemed like the problem was solved. The battery item in the menu bar said it was charging, and eventually said it was fully charged, and the power adapter changed to green. At that time coconutBattery said:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Current Charge | 7030 mAh |
| Full Charge Capacity | 7030 mAh |
| 100% |  |
| Design Capacity | 8755 mAh |
| 80.3% |  |

But while I was posting an answer to the question, it changed to:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Current Charge | 6766 mAh |
| Full Charge Capacity | 7029 mAh |
| 96.3% |  |
| Design Capacity | 8755 mAh |
| 80.3% |  |

The adapter light is still green.

UPDATE 2

The adapter light changed to amber a couple of days after the above update, and the menu says "Battery is not charging". Energy Saver says that the battery is at 98%, but coconutBattery says 76%. Its history viewer shows:

```
Date                Health%     Charge Capacity Cycles
2021-08-01 17:21:28 80.29697    7030    8755    31
2021-08-02 09:10:45 80.28555    7029    8755    31  
2021-08-03 10:01:09 80.01142    7005    8755    31
2021-08-06 00:53:35 77.72701    6805    8755    31
2021-08-09 13:33:42 76.02513    6656    8755    31
```

And System Information says this in the Power tab:

```
Battery Information:

  Model Information:
      Serial Number:    C018104BAG5FWLMF1
      Manufacturer: DP
      Device Name:  bq20z451
      Pack Lot Code:    0
      PCB Lot Code: 0
      Firmware Version: 702
      Hardware Revision:    1
      Cell Revision:    3241

  Charge Information:
      Charge Remaining (mAh):   5959
      Fully Charged:    No
      Charging: No
      Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   6623
      Health Information:
      Cycle Count:  31
      Condition:    Normal
      Battery Installed:    Yes
      Amperage (mA):    0
      Voltage (mV): 12252

AC Charger Information:

  Connected:    Yes
  ID:   0x0100
  Wattage (W):  85
  Revision: 0x0000
  Family:   0x00ba
  Serial Number:    0x00f277bf
  Charging: No
```

So what should I look for to understand why the battery is draining instead of charging?

I tried putting the computer to sleep for a few hours yesterday, it didn't help.

Comment: Could you not just eliminate it being a SMC issue by resetting SMC?

Comment: Probably, just don't want to go through that whole procedure if it doesn't seem like an SMC issue. I hate rebooting.

Comment: It’s really hard to tell if it’s the SMC without resetting the SMC. I’d really recommend you save all your files and do an SMC reset.

Comment: Your reply suggests you haven't even tried a reboot, so probably start with that.

Comment: I actually rebooted a week ago for a different (some programs were hanging).

Comment: I did the SMC reset and it looks like it did the trick. The battery is at 100% now and the light is green.

Comment: And now it looks like the battery is draining again. See the update to the question.

Comment: Maybe this page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211094 will help you more - read carefully -

Comment: If you suspected that the SMC is broken, you can try a easy hardware check CMD + D. If you have no idea which one exacly is not working battery oder smc than reset the SMC.

Comment: @Yoan BHM requires MacOS 10.15.5, I'm running 10.13.6 (but I'll probably upgrade soon).

Comment: I didn't try to drain it. I was just hoping that it would start charging if it's not doing anything.

Comment: If I disconnect the power, I can't use it in clamshell mode.

Comment: I don't have room on my computer table to open the lid and see the external monitor.

Comment: Switched my screen off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the battery replaced. Even if it isn't flagging the 'Needs Servicing' flag, it's six years old, draining rapidly, with a diminished capacity.

80% of original capacity is Apple's threshold to replace the battery. If it's under warranty, they'll do it for free. If not (and yours isn't), you'll have to pay.

If the capacity is much higher, they'll tell you it's fine and to come back when it's lost a bit more!

It's around $200, but the good news is that because of the design, they actually replace the entire 'top half' - the keyboard, trackpad and upper case. So it's a pretty good investment to prolong the life of your Mac.

Comment: I used Option-Click on the battery menu, it says "Condition: Normal".

Comment: But I'll take my Mac to the Genius Bar and have them check it out.

Comment: I took it to the Genius Bar, they said the battery was bad (and it now says "Service Battery" in all the utilities). But it would have taken nearly a week to replace it, and my boss said he couldn't have me offline for that long, so I'm getting a new M1 MacBook instead. But I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your battery is rather old ( ~ 3.5 years ) and had a rather very small cycle count ( ~ 30 ). Then its high level of charge slowly decreased.

I suggest you to fully discharge your battery in one pass.
Unplug your Mac, and let it go to the point where it will make a forced shutdown or switch on hybernate mode. See `pmset -g | grep hibernate`. When you reach the 5 % level, take care to save any
open file, and even better, close any open application.

Next fully charge it in one pass and to its max charge reachable. Check again the output of `coconutBattery`.
If its current charge is pretty near 80% again, then you should
planify your battery replacement.

You don't have to tinker with the SMC ( this is rather a religious trick from bad guys working in support and who respect
procedures rather than analyzing problems ). Many users who apply this reset of the SMC conclude it fixed their problem when in fact in the cases I throughly checked it is just the reboot of MacOS which fixed it.

Comment: I recall that this procedure of fully draining the battery was recommended on older Macs (I did it a few times in the 2000's), but it wasn't recommended on newer ones. Also, the Mac won't run in clamshell mode with power disconnected.

Comment: RE: "You don't have to tinker with the SMC ( this is rather a religious trick from bad guys working in support and who respect procedures rather than analyzing problems )." --  **Apple** states in one of its support documents **"Resetting the System Management Controller (SMC) can resolve certain issues related to power, batteries, fans and other features."**, (emphasis mine), from [How to reset the SMC of your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201295)

Comment: I am sorry to have to inform you than **on many different Macs**, Apple support advised me to reset the SMC and facts prooved that **this tinkering was just a procedure** and didn't fix in any approaching way the original problem ( which in fact was a bad computation of remaining battery charge upon exit of sleeping ). This bug stay unfixed for more than 4 ≠ versions of MacOS.

Comment: I even get to a point where an expert at Apple aknowledged that they don't have internally any tool to diagnose if an SMC is faulty and they follow this stupid procedure because of the lack of such a tool.

Comment: @Barmar, please try my receipe I applied with success. And if it shows to be just a plain stupid religion, just tell me. I will apologize and delete my stupid receipe. The MBP on which I am typing [here] is the exact same one as yours but running 10.13.5.

Comment: Say what you want, it's taken with a grain of salt as I have over the years found for a fact that resetting **SMC** has resolved an issue at that time. I'm not saying it's a cure all, but as I had it work first hand I have to believe there is validity in the process. Just like a full shutdown and startup can and does resolve some issues. You have to start the troubleshooting process somewhere. Your info about draining and recharging the battery is a valid and known procedure, however, it could have been presented without the biased opinion of your last paragraph! So no +1 until its removed.

Comment: Question: If it's not charging now, how can we be sure that it will start charging when I fully drain the battery?

Comment: Just unplug the AC power when you go for your lunch.