# "prevent automatic sleeping" doesn't work for my MBA M1, how do I do

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

I'm trying to stop my MacBook Air M1, 2020 with macOS 13.5.1 from sleeping on power adapter.

I've tried "prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when the display is off" as stated in a [tutorial](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/stop-mac-sleeping-when-display-off)

[image]

I already turned display off to never.

[image]

## pmset command

I've also tried the command `sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1` as stated in a [stackexchange answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361398/359161)

[image]

[image]

## battery settings

[image]

[image]

## question

it still goes to sleep each time about two hours after I leave it idle On Hold, lid open, no matter it's day or night, how do I do?

i start a monitor script when i leave it idle recording timestamp.

Comment: @Alper updated, thanks for reminder

Comment: @Alper “idle On Hold” means power adapter, i didn't lock the screen, it locks itself

Comment: Thx for the update. So you leave the MBA idle with the lid open and connected to power with the above settings and it regularly goes to sleep in about two hours, day or night? Is this accurate? How do you figure out the MBA goes to sleep rather than only the screen being turned off? Can you include a screenshot of the Options in System Settings>Battery>Options in your question?

Comment: Is there a process that you need to run, which is being interrupted by sleep?

Comment: @benwiggy yes, another python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that your python processes prevent sleep from starting when they run, you can use the Terminal command `caffeinate`.

Comment: is it `caffeinate python myscript.py`?

Comment: @JJJohn That's what the man page would suggest.